# Gradual slowing-down of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ado.net

I observe a very odd performance behaviour of a stored procedures which my application calls via an *ADO.NET* connection.
The procedure seems gradually to slow down over time so that after about a month it becomes so slow as to exceed a timeout of 240 seconds, but if one `ALTER`s the procedure without even changing its code, it is cured and completes in about 10 seconds, only to grow slow as cold honey again in another month or so.

When called from the *Management Studio*, however, it always works like new, so I cannot blame aught but the *ADO.NET* interface, although I don't understant how it may be changing the performance of the procedure. I open the connection by means of the simplest connection string contaning only the authentification data and do not change any properties of the `SqlConnection` object.

Could you help me find the cause of this effect?

I have posted the procedure [here](http://pastebin.com/zRZ6sNNh).  The code is not mine and I know it is terribly written but that seems not to be related to the problem, and I plan to rewrite it so that it shall be human-readable and then to optimize it.

Comment: Parameter sniffing, try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or [`WITH RECOMPILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx). The clue is that depending on parameter there can be many execution plans, and one is cached, so it may not be best for different parameter values.

Comment: Try: `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GTGetOrdrDI]
(       @CardCode       nvarchar(30),
        @WhsCode        int
) WITH RECOMPILE` See also [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I am reading the article.

Comment: It might be time to refresh the statistics for your indexes. ([UPDATE STATISTICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx)) Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: I have found that the execution plan depends on the number of entries in `OITL` returned for the sniffed values of `@whsCode` and `@cardCode`.  Whereas the procedure is but occasionally invoked, `WITH RECOMPILE` is a valid solution.